# A good parameter optimization algorithm for a limited number of points with variance

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to meta-optimize an algorithm, which has almost a dosen constants. I guess some form of genetic algorithm should be used. However, the algorithm itself is quite heavy and probabilistic by nature (a version of ant colony optimization). Thus calculating the fitness for some set of parameters is quite slow and the results include a lot of variance. Even the order of magnitude for some of the parameters is not exactly clear, so the distribution on some components will likely need to be logarithmic.

Would someone have ideas about suitable algorithms for this problem? I.e. it would need to converge with a limited number of measurement points and also be able to handle randomness in the measured fitness. Also, the easier it is to implement with Java the better of course. :)

Comment: I think PSO better for you.

Comment: Look up ```black-box optimization``` or ```derivative-free optimization```. This is in general a very hard problem! An [introduction](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dambrosio/blackbox_material/Cassioli_1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to those!

Answer (score 0):

If you can express you model algebraically (or as differential equations), consider trying a derivative-based optimization methods. These have the theoretical properties you desire and are much more computationally efficient than black-box/derivative free optimization methods. If you have a MATLAB license, give fmincon a try. Note: fmincon will work much better if you supply derivative information. Other modeling environments include Pyomo, CasADi and Julia/JuMP, which will automatically calculate derivatives and interface with powerful optimization solvers.